Power BI - restful API
I try to retrieve information to Power BI by using an API token, however, my result is the token by itself instead of the final information. I don't know, what to change in the advanced code.
let
    // Get the API Token
    api_url = "https://apigtwb2c.us.dell.com/",
    grant_type = "client_credentials",
    token_path = "auth/oauth/v2/token",
    client_id = "###############################################",
    client_secret = "############################################",

    EncodedCredentials = "Basic " & Binary.ToText(Text.ToBinary(client_id & ":" & client_secret), BinaryEncoding.Base64),

    Token_Response = Json.Document(Web.Contents(api_url,
    [
        RelativePath = token_path,
        Headers = [#"Content-Type"="application/x-www-form-urlencoded",#"Authorization"=EncodedCredentials],
        Content=Text.ToBinary("grant_type=client_credentials")
    ]
    )
    ),

    //Get the token rom the API response
    token = Token_Respose[access_token],

    // Query the API
    path = "PROD/sbil/eapi/v5/asset-entitlements?servicetags=93YMQ53",
    fields = "all",

    data= Json.Document(Web.Contents(api_url,
    [
        RelativePath = path,
        Query = [fields=fields],
        Headers=[#"Authorization"="Bearer "&token,#"Content-Type"="application/json"]
    ]
    )
    )
    
in
    Token_Response

This is the result:

